# Error for Optional Dependency: xlrd in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to read an Excel file into my Jupyter Notebook using Pandas. However, I keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

Before you say "just install xlrd using pip/conda", that is not an option for me as I'm working on an offline VM and the libraries can only be updated when my company releases a new installation package.

My code is below. I've also tried using pd.read_excel() method as well and get the same error. My plan is to use this then append each sheet to df_data_master.

```
file_name = 'Data\\MillDataMaster.xlsx'
df_data_master = pd.DataFrame()
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to ignore this error since it says it's an optional dependency? Or possibly another way to read in a .xlsx file that doesn't involve pd.ExcelFile or pd.read_excel?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! This is the full error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-66aed5c24499> in <module>
     10 file_name = 'Data\\MillDataMaster.xlsx'
     11 df_data_master = pd.DataFrame()
---> 12 pd.ExcelFile(file_name)
     13 #for i in range(len(file_list)):
     14 #    df_temp1 = pd.read_csv(file_list[i], header=[0])

C:\Users\Public\ProgramingFiles\aitools-deploy\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    817         self._io = _stringify_path(io)
    818 
--> 819         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    820 
    821     def __fspath__(self):

C:\Users\Public\ProgramingFiles\aitools-deploy\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     18         """
     19         err_msg = "Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"
---> 20         import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
     21         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
     22 

C:\Users\Public\ProgramingFiles\aitools-deploy\WPy64-3760\python-3.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\_optional.py in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, raise_on_missing, on_version)
     91     except ImportError:
     92         if raise_on_missing:
---> 93             raise ImportError(message.format(name=name, extra=extra)) from None
     94         else:
     95             return None

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.
```

Comment: within your jupyter environment (assuming you are running a virtual env) `pip3 install xlrd`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. xlrd did not import in Jupyter.

It worked with openpyxl. You can add the engine as an argument to read_excel like this:

```
report = pd.read_excel(report_file, sheet_name = 'data', engine='openpyxl')
```